# AsyncStorage data changing upon app restart

Tags: react-native

I'm currently calling a JSON api to set an auth token which I'll just be storing in the AsyncStorage to persist between app life so a user doesn't have to log in every single time.

I'm currently setting that token like so:

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
  })
    .then( resp => {
      return resp.json();
    })
    .then( async (data) => {
      if ('error' in data) {
        this.setState({
          error: data.error,
          password: ''
        })
        this.secondTextInput.focus();
      }

      if ('access_token' in data) {
        try {
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('access_token', data.access_token);
        } catch (error) {
          return error;
        }

        this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');

      }
    })
    .catch(
      error => {
        console.error(error)
        return error;
      }
    );
```

If I then call `AsyncStorage.getItem('access_token')` **After** killing the app or reloading it I'm winding up with this output:

```
{ 
    "_40":0,
    "_65":0,
    "_55":null,
    "_72":null
}
```

If I then call `AsyncStorage.getItem('access_token')` **Before** killing the app or reloading it I'm winding up with the correct access token. I've double checked the code and I'm not using `AsyncStorage.setItem('access_token')` anywhere else.

This is how I'm retrieving my token:

```
  componentDidMount() {

  console.warn('Mounting');

  try {

      let token = AsyncStorage.getItem('access_token');
      console.warn(token);

      if(token !== null) {
          console.error(token);
      }

  }   catch (error) {}
```

Comment: What's being returned is a Promise. `AsyncStorage.getItem('access_token').then(item => { console.log(item) });`

Comment: Any particular reason why I can receive the data before killing the app? I've just tested this and this works, if you want to create an answer I'll set it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AsyncStorage.getItem() is a asynchronous action just like setItem(), so you need to wait until the Promise has been resolved before logging.

Edit
Tip: if you see some strange output like that it is always related to a Promise which is not yet resolved or rejected

Comment: You can only use `await` in async functions though.

Comment: That's correct, so best put that code in a custom method which you make async and reference that method from componentDidMount()

Comment: Will give it a shot.

Comment: So I created an async function, called `await AsyncStorage.getItem().then(item => {return item})` in it's own function, when I call that function I'm still receiving the promise?

Comment: If you use .then() there is not need for the await anymore. They both do the same thing, but async/await is a newer syntax. If you use both in one line you are in fact creating a new Promise. My advise would be to stick with either .then() or async/await, whichever suits you best.

Comment: `await AsyncStorage.getItem()` just returns the promise object, how would I get my data?

Comment: No await actually resolves the promise, and returns the data

Comment: As above I'm just getting the object with `"_40":0,` etc.

Comment: Try `const item = await AsyncStorage.getItem(access_token)`

Comment: No change, unfortunately. I'll definitely need to look up async/await and learn it more.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my issue by using [@dentemm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5068574/dentemm)'s recommendation of creating an async function.

```
async _getToken() {
try {
    var token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('access_token');

    return token;
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}

componentDidMount() {

let token = null;

this._getToken()
  .then( rsp => {
    fetch(global.url + '/api/auth/refresh', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + rsp
      }
    })
    .then(rsp  => {
      return rsp.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      if('access_token' in data) {
        try {
          AsyncStorage.setItem('access_token', data.access_token);
        } catch (error) {
          return error;
        }
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');
      }
    })
    .catch( error => {
      return error;
    })
  });
}
```

This way I can get my token from the storage then run my refresh function to get an updated token to use for future requests.