# Expo, React Native Async Storage resets after hot reload?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Im developing my own little privat Expo, React Native app using the Expo SDK 32.0.0, and im currently building a auth flow where i get a JWT token through my graphql endpoint and then stores this in AsyncStorage.

I do a log in, everything works i get a token in the async storage, i get redirected as i should to the new stack, then i do a few changes in my code i save it and the app hot reloads, then it when it checks if i have a token it says its undefined and then passes my back to the sign in flow.

So my question is, does the async storage reset after hot reload or is there something im missing?

**Retrival of token after it have been set.**

```js
componentDidMount = async () => {
    const StoredAuth = await AsyncStorage.getItem(Config.STORAGE_AUTH_KEY)
    this.props.navigation.navigate(StoredAuth ? 'App' : 'Auth');
  }
```

Comment: Hello, can you show us how you retrieve the token in your app ? Also, keep in mind that 'AsyncStorage.getItem() is a asynchronous action just like setItem(), so you need to wait until the Promise has been resolved before logging' as said here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50580286/5701319 . If the hot reloading triggers an update in your component where your 'token checking' logic is, it might, I suppose, be problematic .. or not just guessing without the code :\

Comment: @MaieonBrix A small snippet have been added on how i get the key, i use the async / await syntax.

This snippet is from the component that is loaded when the application is loaded as initial navigation stack, then in the CDM i redirect to the stack needed based if there is a token or not.

Answer (score 1):

Hot reload does not affect to `AsyncStorage`. 
Let's suppose you try hot reloading in `App` screen component.

And any place related to `STORAGE_AUTH_KEY` can make unexpected situation in `App` component or `store` you are using like redux and mobx.

You can check how hot reloading works in [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2016/03/24/introducing-hot-reloading).

Comment: Yeah so my issue was i was not handling the async action properly. I was not returning the value of the getItem request, because i decided to write a wrapper round the original Async storage, thanks for the link to the hot reloading works.

Answer (score -1):

Use `expo-secure-store` instead of async storage.

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/